# How to run a function after component loaded at JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, struts2, drop-down-menu

```
      <select id="townid" name="townid">
         <s:iterator value="townsForLanding">
            <option value="<s:property value="id"/>"><s:property value="name"/></option>
         </s:iterator>
      </select>
```

I have a function like this:

```
  $(function(){
     var central = $('#townid option:contains("Central")');
     if(central){
        central.insertAfter('select option:first-child');
     }
  });
```

This function does that: If that dropdwonlist has an element of "Central" puts it after the first option.

My problem is that how can I run that function after that drowdownlist has loaded.

I tried:

```
  $('#townid').one("click", function() {
    $('#townid option:contains("Central")').insertAfter('select option:first-child');
  });
```

However that code has a problem: The list comes Central is not correct place and after that it comes to second place, I mean it doesn't refresh it quickly so I see the change of list. I want it before clicking after load?

Comment: by executed you mean loaded??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting your code inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// call you function here


});
```

Comment: I tried it with $(document).ready(function(){} of course but I had a problem of conflict with prototype framework and fixed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you are welcome but it turned out that my answer ultimately helped me in terms of reputation :) ...